# PaintCode - move object on the path

Tags: ios, swift, paint, bezier

I would like draw a curved line and attach an object to it. Is it possible to create fraction (from 0.0 to 1.0) which makes move my object on the path? When fraction is 0 then object is on the beginning, when 0.5 is on half way and finally when is on 1.0 it is at the end. Of course i want a curved path, not a straight line :) Is it possible to do in PaintCode?

Comment: Not sure if it's the right place to ask, though, but I've tried the same and came to the conclusion: No, it's not possible within PaintCode.

Comment: It's a programming language, so it's entirely possible, but you're missing important information. Should the speed along the path be linear, physics-based, or "whatever"? Because you tagged this with "bezier", which is an utterly non-linear curve: objects moving along bezier curves will do so rather fast along straight sections and slow down proportional to the path curvature. While parameter=distance values 0=0%, 0.5=50% and 1=100% are by definition true, none of the other parameter=distance values will be true for Bezier curves, so just giving those three values isn't enough.

Comment: but i don't need animation. i would like use it as a visual progress bar :) just want set value 0.5 and have my object in half way of the bezier

Comment: that's reading the almost irrelevant bit while not focussing on the important part. A progress bar is linear with distance. Bezier curves are absolutely not, so you answered the question: you need linear curve traversal. See my answer for the actual answer based on that information.

Comment: That's reading the almost irrelevant bit while not focussing on the important part. A progress bar is linear with distance, while Bezier curves are absolutely not, so you need to somehow turn that non-linear Bezier curve traversal into linear curve traversal. See my answer based on that information. And remember: updating a progress bar is most definitely an animation. Sure, it's "bit by bit", but that just makes it a *slow* animation. You're still moving a thing along a curve.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it only **as a progress bar**, it is possible in PaintCode. The trick is to use dashed stroke with very large *Gap* and then just change the *Dash*.

[image: Example]

Then just attach a Variable and you are done.

---

*Edit:* Regarding the discussion under the original post, this solution uses *points* as the unit, so it will be distributed equally along the curve, no matter how curved the bezier is.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you're going to walk along the curve using linear distance, a thing Bezier curves are terrible for, you need to build the linear mapping yourself. That's fairly simple though:

When you draw the curve, also build a look-up table that samples the curve once, at say 100 points (t=0, t=0.01, t=0.02, etc). In pseudocode:

```
lut = [];
lut[0] = 0;
tlen = curve.length();
for(v=0; v<=100; v++) {
  t = v/100;
  clen = curve.split(0,t).length();
  percent = 100*clen/tlen;
  lut[percent] = t;
}
```

This may leave gaps in your LUT - you can either fix those as a secondary step, or just leave them in and do a binary scan on your array to find the nearest "does have a value" percentage.

Then, when you need to show your progress as some percentage value, you just look up the corresponding `t` value: say you need to show 83%, you look up `lut[83]` and draw your object at the value that gives you.